# Territory Management 2.0

Tags: workflow, administration, assignment-rules, territory-management

I'm new to the concept of Territory Management in SFDC. Our organization uses zip codes to assign accounts & leads to sales rep (via assignment rules). As a result we have hundreds of assignment rules in place. We also have other types of assignments for different account types (eg: uses account number to assign). We even have workflows in place to further assign accounts & leads to give visibility to certain people.

We are looking at a new way to manage this but I understand that there's a limit to the Territory Management in SFDC (eg: only 15 Assignment rules?). Anyone here have any experience to share if enabling Territory Management would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Territory Management in SFDC does not work for leads.

PLEASE up vote this salesforce suggestion to make this feature applicable to leads (I didn't start the post, but our company could definitely use this improvement as well) here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqCOAA0

In the mean time, there are a number of options listed here:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006792&language=en_US

We use the custom zip code territory object with zip codes as individual records with rep positions as custom look-up fields to users. This also allows us to write triggers to assign these users as owners of any object based on their zip code territory or the postal code value populated on that zip code territory.